# Qt Creator - Gui Application - Build Error - Cannot find -IGL

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, compiler-errors, qt-creator

I literally just started learning how to program with Qt. Forgive my ignorance. I was hoping someone could help me resolve my issue.

After installation, I wanted to start by checking everything was ok with an arbitrary build of a scratch Qt gui application but I got the following errors.

```
:-1: error: cannot find -lGL
:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not sure what other information is relevant- I didn't alter the template code in any way. If I can help by supplying any other information just let me know.

Hopefully it's an easy fix. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install the libGL library plus the developer packages.

Comment: Install with Qt Creator or terminal?

Comment: It's a library separate from Qt. If you're using Ubuntu, you can install it with the command 'sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev'